How can I kill mold and seal up this door?
https://photos.app.goo.gl/ejRfZhvfrbzd8um9A
I moved in with a friend who rents basement unit. After 5 or so years, babysitter moved out so I'm moving in the bedroom. While cleaning I found This door and opened it and such horrible smell came through. Realized that's why the bedroom smells every time I go in. The owners have garage on cinder block I believe. So I don't know where this leads to But the garage is right in front of this bedroom. I did a mold test kit and It grew some nasty looking stuff. Haven't sent it out to a lab yet b/c costs money and I've already bought a dehumidifier and other things to try. I'm just wondering how I could possibly seal this door back to the wall because when I pull open the latch to open the trap, the main surrounding piece/panel pulls right off wall. There's like black mold. Looks like growing on the textured paint. I've tried covering with plastic but tape won't stay And the parts that did stay the plastic is just covered with moisture dripping. Bought a dehumidifier. When I first put hand in there I grabbed a bunch of black wet slimy pieces that seemed to be falling apart. I know it is going to be a long haul for whatever needs to be fixed. But I was wondering if anyone knows how I could get the frame/panel? of this door to seal back to the wall And door sealed shut so that smell or mold is not leaking into the bedroom. I don't know anything about this stuff. I've done research And thought maybe if I use a vinegar and water spray And spray into the cavity it could kill The mold growing on the concrete. I think it's concrete anyway. When I reach my arm in the hole and take pictures up and down with flashlight it looks like concrete or some type of cement just crumbling apart. Maybe some kind of damp rid product inside? I wanted to paint the wall so that it is not textured to tape over the door area but again, not sure if that will help. Also thought of pulling trap door completely out And covering with another piece of drywall/plywood. It looks like mold spores growing on the textured part of the wall. The babysitter that lived in the room had an AC unit built for the sliding door And has never taken it out. It would run all year long. Ac unit is still in, But I cleaned filters and it's also hot and summer so I'm keeping the AC floor unit in until the fall. I don't know what to even call this. Maybe crawl space? I don't know but I know I cannot crawl inside. Talking to the owner is Not my place, I'm hoping my friend who rents is going to show them the mold kit. But In the meantime, I need to do something temporary since I already bought a bed and frame that are being held at two different furniture stores and I said I would pick up this week. Does anyone have any ideas?

Mold is quite easy to kill.  Bleach and some other household cleaners will kill and there is stuff you can buy in stores called mold killers.  Keeping the mold away is the hard part.  Removing where the moisture comes from.

where is the mold in the pictures? ... I see a pile of ash in the last few pictures

@jsotola perhaps here?

That looks more like dirt than mold.  The area appears to be extremely dry which is non supporting for mold to grow.

If you look closely at the picture of door, There's  black stuff all around the perimeter.Looks like it's crawling up the wall.Theres other spots on the wall that have blackish color.Also when I first opened it I grabbed a handful of Black stuff and it smelled like if a piece of fruit went bad and moldy. Also the test shows it's growing stuff. It's a mold armor test kit. I'll try to add the picture of that as well.I just want to be able to seal The frame around the door or take it out to somehow cover it.If you walk in the room The musty moldy smell hits like a ton of bricks.

No the area was not actually dry until I bought dehumidifier and put next to it. 0

I added some more pictures. If you notice the mold kit, it's definitely growing something. It's probably gotten dry now because of dehumidifier I just bought and put next to it. It was super wet when I first opened it and grabbed a handful of Horrible smelling black pieces.. like the smell of rotted fruit with fuzz and mold on it

Please... 1) See [ask]. 2) Revise to remove all extra commentary about your life and your feelings that isn't relevant to this question. 3) Break that wall of text into sensible paragraphs. 4) Take the [tour]. 5) Don't post "thanks" comments. Follow the process to show gratitude and select the best answer.

I don't see any mold in the pictures except around the little door. You are living alongside a chimney on a basement level in a house with poor moisture mitigation and apparently little insulation.
Old homes were never meant to have finished basements. Back when basements were cellars, chimneys were built all the way down to the bottom of the foundation. The main level had a fireplace with an opening to a chute down to the bottom of the fireplace. When cleaning out the fireplace, you just opened the door and dumped it down the chute. You could collect ashes from the basement door once they cooled and without spreading them around the house. When heating a house transitioned from wood fires to furnaces, furnaces vented out of chimneys which helped a little to vent out moisture during cold, wet seasons. These chimneys needed to be lined to increase function and ventilation (exhaust gasses were too lazy to dissipate safely through the top). But now modern, efficient gas furnaces have to be vented through dedicated exhaust vents. I guess now the chimney is completely unused which is contrary to its function. Even if the occasional winter fire is lit for aesthetics, ashes are probably swept from the fireplace directly. In any case, unused chimneys collect a lot of moisture and potentially organic material from bird nests and they smell pretty terrible. Bricks are basically sponges.
Mold cultures are useless. They're too sensitive. There's mold literally everywhere unless you're in an operating room or a microchip processing plant. All mold is bad for you, but if you have a competent immune system, normal household living is not a life-threatening thing. If you can smell it or see it, this is a problem. Your nose is the best indicator.
Unfortunately, I would guess the basement renovation did not use a vapor barrier against the old chimney, and I would guess the basement doesn't have any insulation at all. The best thing is to deprecate (unbuild) chimneys that are not used. A reasonable compromise is to request a chimney cap be instated (even if the chimney is in use).
As a renter, I would tape a vapor barrier over the wall, stick a board of foam insulation over the whole wall, and paint the rest of the closet with oil based killz. Any improvement to ventilation and filtration at all is a good idea. Dehumidifiers are great tools if the humidity is high - habitating the basement means having the heat through the winter in a space that was traditionally too cold for mold to grow. Target humidity sub 50%. Vaccuum often, wash walls and windows with a disinfectant often.

I do know that the owners just had someone come and evaluate walls because apparently they are re-insulating entire house. That will be from the outside. Maybe that will help the situation

@SandraFoley It will not unfortunately. Your house is probably balloon framed. What this means is that the studs span from the main level of the house to the attic, so they can pour loose fill insulation between the studs of the wall. The basement level is a poured concrete foundation and possibly a pony wall. None of the loose fill will enter any farther than the sill plate which is at the bottom of the main level. You need a special arrangement to insulate (and ventilate) the basement.

And yes, we also do have many many trees around the home with a large amount of birds so that would make sense
